# Android table layout adding rows with data

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a homepage that's filled with data. So far I have been populating list views with the data, but for the homepage there are 3 lots of data and I can't put them in list view because they all scroll independently. So I want to create a table layout, so it goes:

```
header
xml header
table row
xml header 2
table row

xml header 3
table row
table row
table row
table row
table row
```

I want each row to have an image and a text view, but also in underneath xml header 3 I want the rows to load based on the data so if I have five pieces of data it loads 5 rows etc.

Also can a table row have an on Click Event listener.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

   <include layout="@layout/header" />
   <include layout="@layout/redcell" />

   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="60dp" >
   </TableRow>

   <include layout="@layout/redcell" />

   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="60dp" >
   </TableRow>

    <include layout="@layout/redcell" />


    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   />

</TableLayout>
```

here is where I load the data

```
public void loadData(){String myhash = buildHmacSignature(apiKey, fixturesFeedURL);





    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(fixturesFeedURL);

    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestToken", myhash));
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("apiUser", apiUser));

    try {
        post.setEntity (new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String json = reader.readLine();
        fulldata = String.valueOf(json);
        Log.v("myApp","newsdata" + fulldata);
        newsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);    
        JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("news");


           for(int t = 0; t < newsAmount; t++){
               JSONObject newsTitleDict = jArray.getJSONObject(t);


               newsList.add(newsTitleDict.getString("title"));

           }


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, newsList));

       ListView list = getListView();

        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



    }   


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        checkPreferences();
        loadData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried tu use a custom listView, if you are receiving the data in a Json is much better to use a custom listView

here is a somehow good tutorial, that explain how to add text an images to every row on the list

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

also if you need 3 columns that scroll independently you can use 3 listViews, you will see an example of how to make many scroolviews on the google apidemos

Comment: no i don't want 3 to scroll independently i want the whole thing to scroll as one which is why I'm looking of an alternative to list view but i appreciate your comments very useful